# MakeFile to Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, makefile

Currently i am using makefile to build the project but i want to convert it into visual studio 2010 project? After some research i can not find a single tutorial or guide to do this. Can any one help me by pointing to any of the relevant resource or step by step guide for it. 
P.S: I have only elementary knowledge of makefile

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061381/convert-a-makefile-to-a-vs-project

Comment: @yegorich:- If I do it manually, how will i decide which Flag of MakerFile will correspond to what in visual studio project?

Comment: That's a good question. SO far I was just going to compiler/linker flags and looked at different options and tried to determine, what flags the produce. With CMake you can just reuse the flags as they are: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/Od /D \"_DEBUG\" /RTCs /D \"_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS\" /MDd /GS /W3 /nologo /c /Zi /TP" CACHE STRING "MSVC MT flags " FORCE)`

Comment: Look at these tools: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake#Basic_CMakeLists.txt_from-scratch-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake#Tutorials) for creating VS projects. You just define your project structure, i.e. sources, headers, resources and CMake creates appropriate project/solution files for your target IDE: makefiles, Visual Studio etc.

After installation CMake provides a GUI, where you can choose your target IDE.

I know, this is not a direct answer to your question, but it is a way to make your projects more portable.