# Translate basic Makefile to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, makefile

I'm trying to build some open source software that usually runs on Linux.  The authors have provided a Makefile which creates some object files (*.so) that are used downstream (in lua).  I usually do all my development in Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows machine.  Can anyone direct me on how to translate what looks like a pretty basic Makefile into a Visual Studio project.  I have torch, png++, and OpenCV installed on my system (just not installed in the arrangement specified in the Makefile, below).  I just need to figure out how to configure the Visual Studio project to point at the headers/libraries on my system and to create the object files specified.  Here is the Makefile:

```
PREFIX=$(HOME)/torch/install
CFLAGS=-I$(PREFIX)/include/THC -I$(PREFIX)/include/TH -I$(PREFIX)/include
LDFLAGS_NVCC=-L$(PREFIX)/lib -Xlinker -rpath,$(PREFIX)/lib -lluaT -lTHC -lTH -lpng
LDFLAGS_CPP=-L$(PREFIX)/lib -lluaT -lTH `pkg-config --libs opencv`

all: libadcensus.so libcv.so

libadcensus.so: adcensus.cu SpatialLogSoftMax.cu
    nvcc -arch sm_35 -O3 -DNDEBUG --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o libadcensus.so --shared adcensus.cu $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_NVCC)

libcv.so: cv.cpp
    g++ -fPIC -o libcv.so -shared cv.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_CPP)

clean:
    rm -f libadcensus.so libcv.so
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to figure out how to configure the Visual Studio project

You just said a mouthful.  You're going to have to understand every line of the Makefile, and then express that information to VS.  It *might* be easiest to use a "makefile project" in VS, and convert the Makefile to be usable by **NMAKE** and **CL.EXE**.  If you do, keep their documentation bookmarked.

Else you'll have to add the library paths etc. to a VS project through the usual dialogs.

All those `-l` items refer to libraries you'll need.  IIRC **CL** recognizes that syntax.

On Windows, you will not need:

```
-Xlinker -rpath,$(PREFIX)/lib
```

because the COFF format doesn't have an RPATH.  You also won't be able to use

```
`pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

which produces the `opencv` libraries as a linker command list.  You'll need to know what they are, and include them explicitly.

I suppose you know that your target is a DLL, not a .so.

HTH.

Comment: James,  Thanks for the tips.  Based on your advice (and the answer posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061381/convert-a-makefile-to-a-vs-project), I'm proceeding by creating a DLL project in Visual Studio.  I *think* I have on my system all of the libraries specified.  But I'm quite inexperienced in reading Makefiles.  Is there a resource online that can help me interpret each line of the above file?