# Importing a folder into Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-2017

I am a college student and often I am given project folders for courses with multiple C++ header files, source files, and a makefile usually. I am using Visual Studio 2017 for reference.

Visual studio is my favorite IDE for debugging but I do not know how to integrate one of these folders into Visual Studio so I might debug from the application and not from a terminal. I am wondering if someones knows a way for me to open this folder in VS, and run/debug it like a normal console application? I realize the makefile might add an additional layer of complexity.

[This is an image of the contents of a folder I want to be able to run/debug/execute normally in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5V3B.png)

I can open this folder in visual studio by right clicking -> open in visual studio.

However when in visual studio, I cannot build, run, debug or anything. Visual studio is acting more like a text editor than an actual IDE. I would like to be able to build/make my program through visual studio so I can launch/debug it in visual studio.

Comment: Ehh, it has literally "Open folder" menu item, is that what you are looking for? Also why not create a normal solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a makefile to a VS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061381/convert-a-makefile-to-a-vs-project)

Comment: @VTT I can open this folder in visual studio. However, I cannot make my solution or run the program from visual studio. Mainly I would like to use the debugger.

Comment: So what prevents you from making a solution or running your program from VS?

Comment: @VTT I posted an update with a picture. This isn't a VS project I am being given. I am just given some .cpp files and .h files along with a makefile. Visual studio, when it opens this folder, will not let me do anything besides view/edit these files. I cannot run or make these files like one can do with a normal console application.

Comment: As far as I can tell according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=vs-2017 you should be able to run and debug projects using the Open Folder feature.