# Makefile with MSVC and CLION

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, clion, atl

I use the ATL library so I have to use MSVC instead of MinGW. But with MSVC libraries written in Makefile are not seen (with Makefile they are). I suppose that MSVC doesn't see Makefile at all. Are there any supposes about how to compile the project?

```
# Remove NDEBUG define to trigger asserts
CPPFLAGS+=-O2 -std=gnu++11 -I. -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DOPENSSL
LDFLAGS+=-levent -lstdc++ -lssl -lcrypto

uname_S := $(shell sh -c 'uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not')
ifeq ($(uname_S),FreeBSD)
  CXX=clang++
  LIBEVENT_HOME=D:/ProximaX/d/vcpkg/vcpkg/packages/libevent_x86-windows
  CPPFLAGS+=-I${LIBEVENT_HOME}/include
  LDFLAGS+=-L${LIBEVENT_HOME}/lib
else
  CXX?=g++
  LIBEVENT_HOME=D:/ProximaX/d/vcpkg/vcpkg/packages/libevent_x86-windows
  CPPFLAGS+=-I${LIBEVENT_HOME}/include
  LDFLAGS+=-L${LIBEVENT_HOME}/lib
  OPENSSL_HOME=D:/ProximaX/d/vcpkg/vcpkg/packages/openssl_x86-windows
  CPPFLAGS+=-I${OPENSSL_HOME}/include
  LDFLAGS+=-L${OPENSSL_HOME}/lib
  ATL_HOME=D:/VS17/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/atlmfc
  CPPFLAGS+=-I${ATL_HOME}/include
  LDFLAGS+=-L${ATL_HOME}/lib
endif

all: swift-dynamic

swift: swift.o sha1.o compat.o sendrecv.o send_control.o hashtree.o bin.o binmap.o channel.o transfer.o httpgw.o statsgw.o cmdgw.o avgspeed.o avail.o storage.o zerostate.o zerohashtree.o livehashtree.o live.o api.o content.o swarmmanager.o address.o livesig.o exttrack.o

swift-static: swift
    ${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} -o swift *.o ${LDFLAGS} -static -lrt
    strip swift
    touch swift-static

swift-dynamic: swift
    ${CXX} ${CPPFLAGS} -o swift *.o ${LDFLAGS}
    touch swift-dynamic

clean:
    rm -f *.o swift swift-static swift-dynamic 2>/dev/null

.PHONY: all clean swift swift-static swift-dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not use makefiles. You need to create a project and configure it correctly. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061381/convert-a-makefile-to-a-vs-project).

That is why libraries that target both Windows and Linux provide both a makefile and a Visual Studio project file. Or they use a "meta build tool", such as CMake, that can generate both from the same source.

Alternatively you can rewrite the makefile to call the Visual Studio compiler but the compilation and linking options will be different.

Comment: I want to deploy this library https://github.com/libswift/libswift. It uses ATL (so I must use MSVC) but uses also Makefile

Comment: You should issue a ticket on GitHub and ask for an explanation on how to build on Windows. It will not work with the provided Makefile, because it is Linux specific.